# Image does not load when using canvas.loadFromJSON in Fabric.js 1.3.0

Tags: fabricjs

I'm using the latest version:

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.3.0/fabric.min.js

The test code below simulates a canvas you will save after 1 second. Then load it from JSON. This works on older versions, then on 1.3.0 it stopped working. You would have to keep putting some timeout like:

```
setTimeout( function(){canvas.renderAll()},500);
```

to make it work at times but not all the time.

```
var img= "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png";          
fabric.Image.fromURL(img, function(img) {
        img.set({
        left: 200,
        top: 200   
    });   
    canvas.add(img); 
    canvas.renderAll();
}); 
 setTimeout( function(){
    var json=JSON.stringify(canvas);
    canvas.clear();         
    canvas.loadFromJSON(json);
    canvas.renderAll(); 
    //setTimeout( function(){canvas.renderAll()},500) // adding a timeout seems to be the only fix.
 },1000)
```

how do I make it render without adding some timeouts like before ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just use

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(json,canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

Comment: Hi I tried it here http://upmcwest.com/rinkupdates/boardjs/f1.htm ( click view source )
and the result is the same.

Comment: Just updated the above answer - use `loadFromJSON` instead of `loadFronJson`.

Comment: Yep that did it! I think on this version if the JSON has an image, it takes some time to render all and you will get a flicker.

Comment: This works for me on fabric 1.5.0. But tell me please do you know what is the purpose of second argument and why do you need to bind to canvas it self, why is it not enough just to call renderAll(). This is very strange behaviour. Thanks for the answer.